# find a formula for the sum of combination

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$5^n {n\choose 0} - 5^{n-1} {n\choose 1} + 5^{n-2}{n\choose2} +...... \pm{n\choose n}$

I was trying to use binomial theorem, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: $(5-1)^n$?..... I guess there is a sum of $n+1$ terms, not only those you've written. Write out the formula for $(5-1)^n$ and see what you get.

Comment: @freak_warrior, yes, that's what I mean, didn't figure out how to type out that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$5^n {n\choose 0} - 5^{n-1} {n\choose 1} + 5^{n-2}{n\choose2} +...... \pm{n\choose n}=$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(-1)^k5^{n-k}=(-1+5)^n\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

$${5^n} {n\choose 0} - 5^{n-1} {n\choose 1} + 5^{n-2} {n\choose2} -...\pm {n\choose n}\\=
{5^n}{(-1)^0} {n\choose 0}+5^{n-1}{(-1)^1}{n\choose 1} + 5^{n-2}{(-1)^2} {n\choose2} -...{5^0}{(-1)^n}  {n\choose n}$$

Now use the Binomial Theorem

then it should be $(5-1)^n = 4^n$

Comment: can you be more detailed how it works? I'm still confused.